# Trace operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, trace

A compact linear operator $A$ over a separable Hilbert space $H$ is said to be in the trace class or in the nuclear operator space if for some (and hence all ) orthonormal bases $(e_{n})$ of $H$ the trace norm
$$\Vert A \Vert_{tr} = Tr| A |= \sum_{n}\langle ( A ^{\ast} A ) ^{\frac{1}{2}} e_{ n} , e_{ n} \rangle$$
is finite.
In this case $$TrA=\sum_{n}\langle A e_{ n} , e_{ n} \rangle$$ converges absolutely and is independent of the choice of the orthonormal basis.

Moreover,we have
$$\Vert A \Vert_{tr} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Vert A e_{n} \Vert<\infty$$

The trace norm also can be characterized as follows

$$\Vert A\Vert_{tr}= sup \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle A e_{ n} , f_{ n} \rangle|$$

Where the supremum is taken over any pair of orthonormal bases   $\{e_n\}$ and $\{f_n\}$

My question is :
Can we characterize the trace norm to be 
$$\Vert A \Vert_{tr} =sup \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Vert A e_{n} \Vert$$
Where the supremum is taken over any orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy to show that, if $A$ is trace-class,
$$\tag{1}
\|A\|_{\rm tr}=\min\left\{\sum_n\|Af_n\|:\ \{f_n\}\ \text{ orthonormal basis}\right\}.
$$
Note that since $\|Ax\|=\|\,|A|x\,\|$, we may assume that $A$ is positive. So $A=\sum_n\lambda_j\,e_n\otimes e_n$ for a decreasing sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ with $\lambda_n\searrow0$, and $\{e_n\}$ an orthonormal basis. Thus
$$
\|A\|_{\rm tr}=\sum_n\langle |A|e_n,e_n\rangle=\sum_n\langle Ae_n,e_n\rangle=\sum_n\lambda_n=\sum_n\|Ae_n\|.
$$
For an arbitrary orthonormal basis $\{f_n\}$, we have 
$$
\|A\|_{\rm tr}=\sum_n\langle Af_n,f_n\rangle\leq\sum_n\|Af_n\|.
$$
So $(1)$ is established.

Comment: This might be silly but, does $\sum_{n}||Af_n||<\infty$ holds for all orthonormal basis $\{f_n\}$, as mentioned by OP?

Comment: I think that's not true, cannot get my head around it though.

Comment: I would think it's false, but I'm not sure. I'll try to think about it.